# Why aren't my RequiredFieldValidators stopping the form from posting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

Per the erroneously indicated "duplicate", no validation occurs when the button is clicked. The postback proceeds unimpeded by validation behavior. I thought I was clear on this when I said *"the page is still posting"* but apparently I was wrong.

This shouldn't be so confusing but I'm lost.

I've got several `RequiredFieldValidator` controls on my page in which I'm not specifying an `InitialValue` so the validators should fail to validate if the `ControlToValidate`'s value is empty ([according to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_RequiredFieldValidator_InitialValue)).

The page is still posting, however, even with empty values (although `Page.IsValid` returns false in this case).

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Registered Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="RegisteredName" CssClass="form-control" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RegisteredNameRequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="RegisteredName" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Save" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Save_Click" CausesValidation="true" />
</div>
```

Here's the backend code:

```
protected async void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            // Save the form data to the database.
            var company = await SaveCompany();
            await SaveCompanyMeta(company);
            await SaveBankingDetails(company);
            await SaveContacts(company);
            await SaveShareholders(company);

            // Indicate that the operation processed successfully.
            var msg = $"Company details for new company {company.RegisteredName} have been saved. Redirecting to company list...";
            ShowSnackbar(msg, "/Companies");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowSnackbar(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now I'm more than happy to leave this as-is considering it still prevents corrupt data from being posted to the database, but the fact that it doesn't indicate anything on the UI is what I'm having a problem with.

I've gone and built this more or less according to [asp.net-tutorials.com](https://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/required-field-validator/) but I'm not having any luck getting it to work correctly. Have I missed something? Why isn't this showing any errors on the page when validation fails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Required Field Validator Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261050/required-field-validator-not-firing)

Comment: @hardkoded you know, every time I post a question on this site, someone like you comes in almost instantly and does this; trying to kill it before anyone can assist so I guess thanks for sticking to tradition (not that its helpful in the least) but you're dead wrong about the duplicate as that indicated question which I didn't find on a google search doesn't solve this for the reason I indicated on my edit at the top of the question.

Comment: Don't take a duplicate close as an offense. It's part of making Stack Overflow a better place. It is way better to have one question and try to find a solution there, than having many questions. For you and the next to come. Again, don't take that as aggression, take that as a way of improving the site. If you think it's not a duple, others might think the same and the question won't be closed. Again it's all for the best. I invested time reading your question and found that it's similar to the other question, that's all.

Comment: Please, explain how you are implementing the form post. Which control are you using for posting?

Comment: @hardkoded its a way to not help people who need it so I do take it as an offense.

Comment: @JotaBe I updated the question to add the markup for the button.

Comment: @hardkoded no, it's not, it's (among other things) a way to point people in the direction of resources which probably already answer the question. It takes several votes to close a question though, so it won't get closed unless a number of other experienced users agree. In the meantime, you have pointed out why you don't think the nominated duplicate is a match. Having given it a quick read, I think you're probably right in this case.

Comment: You mentioned that Page.IsValid still returns false, so it implies the validation control is working, but that there's a problem with the client-side validation. This could be caused by a couple of things. Do you have any JavaScript errors in your browser's Console at the time when you're trying to submit the form? That might stop the JavaScript validation code from executing.

Comment: @Ortund get sure that the required validation scripts are being loaded by the browser. The question referred by hardkoded mention these scripts.

Comment: @Ortund sorry the above comment I aimed at hardkoded was supposed to be aimed at you...too late to edit it now

Answer (score 0):

Worked around by adding the HTML5 `required` attribute to the fields that I want to validate. Either on its own or along with the logic already in place, the form submission is now not happening and the UI indicates that the field is required:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="RegisteredName" CssClass="form-control" required />
```

Comment: This will work client-side, but you have, in the process, removed the server-side validation which an ASP.NET Validation control would create behind the scenes (and which is important for data integrity - client-side validation is quite easy for a malicious user to bypass). So while this is a workaround which superficially solves the issue, it's not a directly equivalent replacement of the functionality.